# Работает ли у вас Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

Уже три дня как перестала работать база данных Firebase. То есть во всех приложениях тупо не выводится информация из базы, никаких ошибок не выдает. При входе в консоль показывает, что баз данных нет. При попытке создать новую выводит ошибку. Что такое и куда обращаться? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень возможно, что в РосКомНадзор. Проверьте IP-адреса.

Comment: аналогично, firebase недоступен... Изначально блокировка проявилась у мегафона, и уже как два дня у ростелекома... В РКН написал, пока тишина.

Comment: Уфа, уфанет, с сегодняшнего дня все заработало. Спасибо ребятам, кто написал в РКН. У остальных как?

Comment: В СПб пока не работает

Comment: Ураа! Блокировка снята! Как раз позавчера написал обращение и вот на тебе - открыли!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

РКН заблокировали IP-адрес, на котором находится сервер БД у Firebase. Во всех проектах теперь не видно БД. Авторизация через Firebase API не работает. При попытке создать новую БД выводится ошибка "Null". Я спрашивал у тех поддержки, и они подтвердили блокировку IP. Написал на горячую линию РКН, пока все глухо... Проверял на 4-ех интернет-провайдерах. Сами страдаем от этого. У пользователей не из России данной проблемы нет. Остается только ждать действий от Google или разблокировки...

Comment: К сожалению, вы подтвердили мои опасения :( Ну что ж, будем ждать, спасибо

Comment: Если через прокси открывать - всё работает

Comment: Это понятно, что через прокси или VPN будет работать. В этом случае таблицы становятся видны в проектах, но ведь не заставишь всех юзеров приложения в русском сегменте ставить VPN, чтобы оно у них заработало.

Comment: у меня в приложении firebase database работает нормально

Comment: Проблема наблюдается только в России.

Comment: @Mealtris я из России

Comment: @ValeryPonomarenko VPN? Proxy? У меня на четырех провайдерах в профиле пустые БД и запрос на авторизацию не проходит из приложений. Работает только через VPN.

Comment: @Mealtris ничего нет, пробовал через моб инет Beeline и через рабочий вайфай (какой провайдер - не знаю)

Comment: До вчерашнего дня базу хоть посмотреть можно было,а сегодня даже сайт с консолью FireBase не открывается!

Comment: Блокировка с Realtime DB снята. РКН игнорил более месяца письма на своих трех адресах, что было ожидаемо... Скорее всего что то сделали технари гугла. Но до сих пор мертва Asana, часто не грузятся изображения в гуглодоках и вот на днях заметил, что инсталлер огненной лисы не работает, пока не дашь ему VPN... Да и гора других сервисов и форумов к различным SDK тоже мертвы без VPN. Психанул, купил на офис VPN на год и поставил на роутер. Так не поработаешь...

Answer (score 4):

Можно сообществом письмо написать РКН, чтобы сняли блокировку. В гилд варс тоже нельзя было загрузиться, ребята написали, и блокировка снялась.