# Почему я не могу создать бд на Firebase?Что за ошибка?

Tags: firebase, firebase-database, realtime

Ошибка при создании RealtimeDatabse. В чем дело?
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работает ли у вас Firebase?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816166/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%81-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дубликат.
[Работает ли у вас Firebase?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816166/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-firebase)

РКН заблокировали IP-адрес, на котором находится сервер БД у Firebase. Во всех проектах теперь не видно БД. Авторизация через Firebase API не работает. При попытке создать новую БД выводится ошибка "Null". Я спрашивал у тех поддержки, и они подтвердили блокировку IP. Написал на горячую линию РКН, пока все глухо... Проверял на 4-ех интернет-провайдерах. Сами страдаем от этого. У пользователей не из России данной проблемы нет. Остается только ждать действий от Google или разблокировки...

Поработать с БД можно через VPN или прокси, но вот в приложении вероятно работать не будет. По крайней мере без VPN у меня приложения авторизацию пройти не могут через Firebase...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я так и думала. Ужас...Будем ждать

Comment: @AlenaSapronova отметьте ответ как правильный, если он вам помог)