# Firebase как обойти блокировку Роскомнадзора

Tags: веб-программирование, firebase, angular5

РКН заблокировал нецензурно много IP адресов Google. Под горячую руку попал сервис Firebase и при написании приложения и использования в нем Firebase ничего не происходит до тех самых пор пока не включишь VPN.

Решение которое я нашел в интернете это проксирование веб-сокетов. Знает кто нибудь как это делается или другие способы обхода без использования VPN с описанием.

//В итоге я купил VPN от Каспериков за 300 руб на месяц. (•◡•)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему я не могу создать бд на Firebase?Что за ошибка?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/816285/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-firebase%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста что в итоге вы сделали с VPN от Каспериков?